# This code works great for almost every testcase except when the element to be deleted is the 2nd last element from the end of the list

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

**The program is for deleting a node from a double linked list and printing out the new list**

The code works great for almost every testcase except when the element to be deleted is the 2nd last element from the end of the list.
When that is given I get a segmentation fault error in my delete function, which i just have not been able to fix and hope to get fixed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//no work
struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

struct node *head = NULL;
void display();
void addnode(int x){
    struct node *current = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    current->data = x;
    current->next = NULL;
    current->prev = NULL;

    if (head == NULL)
        head = current;
    else{
        struct node *temp;
        for (temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next);
        temp->next = current;
        current->prev = temp;
    }
}

void delete(int t){
    struct node *temp;
    if (head->next == NULL){
        if (head->data != t)
            printf("Target Element is Not Found\n");
        else{
            display();
            printf("List is Empty\n");
        }
    }else{
        for (temp = head; temp->next != NULL && temp->data != t; temp = temp->next);
        if (temp->data == t){
            if (temp->next != NULL){
                temp->next->next->prev = temp;
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
            }
        }
    }
}

void display(){
    struct node *temp;
    printf("List->");
    for (temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
    printf("%d->NULL\n", temp->data);
}

int main(){
    int n, temp;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    while (n--){
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        addnode(temp);
    }
    int t;
    scanf("%d", &t);
    
    display();
    delete(t);
    display();
}
```

There seem to be some world limit for this so let me try to fill that up very quick. Cuz i really want to earn some reputation and finally ask a whole bunch of stuff i wanted to ask.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nke8q.png

Comment: Please post the output as text, not as an image. You may want to read this for further information: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: In C you [don't have to (and really shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858).

Comment: Also, what happens in `delete` if the list is empty (i.e. when `head == NULL`)?

Comment: Re “There seem to be some [word] limit for this so let me try to fill that up very quick”: When a rule prevents you from doing something, your response should be “Why does this rule exist and what can I do to work with that goal?” not “How can I defeat this rule?”

Comment: As for the crash, this is a very good time to learn how to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your programs. For example by using a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: I also recommend you use pencil and paper to follow along what you're doing in the `delete` function, by starting with the list you have using squares for the nodes, and arrows for all pointers and links. As you modify pointers and links, erase and redraw the arrows on paper. Does it all make sense on the paper?

Comment: `for (temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)` is a recipe for disaster on an empty list (e.g. `head` is `NULL` on encounter).

Comment: So far i can tell that my code does exceptionally bad at handling null values, so ill have to work my way around that. Though i fixed this problem a while back thanks to all the suggestions made by everyone. I found this much needed and very helpful feedback to be very useful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I read the article for not casting in malloc. But i havent been able to implement it for struct, can you help me with that?

Comment: `struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

Answer (score 2):

When `temp` points to the node to be deleted, and it is the next-to-last, then `temp->next` is not null but `temp->next->next` is, and your code attempts to execute `temp->next->next->prev = temp;`. Since `temp->next->next` is null, using `temp->next->next->prev` does not work. You need to rethink what your code is doing and why.

Answer (score 0):

> The code works great for almost every testcase except when the element to be deleted is the 2nd last element from the end of the list.

I don't agree and below is the reason:

Multiple problems in your `delete()` function.

- Major *(you are already aware of this)*: If the list has more than `1` elements in it and, for deletion, user entered second last node to delete then segmentation fault is occurring. Its because of this in `delete()`:

  ```
                temp->next->next->prev = temp;
  ```

`temp->next->next` is `NULL` and your code is attempting to access `NULL` pointer.

- Major: If the list contain only one element and if you give that element as input to delete, it will output - `List is Empty` and node with that value will not be deleted:

  ```
    if (head->next == NULL){
        if (head->data != t)
            printf("Target Element is Not Found\n");
        else{
            display();
            printf("List is Empty\n");
        }
    ....
    ....
  ```
- Major: If the list has more than `1` elements in it and, for deletion, user entered any node to delete other than last and second last node, the `delete()` will end up deleting the node next to the node entered by user (which is supposed to be delete). Moreover, there is memory leak in this scenario.

  ```
        if (temp->data == t){
            if (temp->next != NULL){
                temp->next->next->prev = temp;
                temp->next = temp->next->next;
            }
        ....
        ....
  ```

All statements are making changes in `temp->next` pointer and not in `temp` pointer. Also, deleted node memory is not freed up anywhere.

- Major:  If the list has more than `1` elements in it and, for deletion, user entered last node, no deletion will happen and the last node will remain part of list. Its because of this in `delele()`:

  ```
        if (temp->data == t){
            if (temp->next != NULL){
  ```

If `temp` is pointing to last node then `temp->next` will be `NULL`.

- Minor: If the list has more than `1` elements in it and, for deletion, user entered some node which does not exists in the list than no output message to inform this to the user.

Problem in `display()` function:

- Major: Pass `NULL` to `display()` function and it will give segmentation fault. This will be the case when your list will have only one element and that element will be deleted then the list will be empty and when `display()` will be called after `delete()`, it will result in segmentation fault. It's because of this in `display()`:

  ```
    for (temp = head; temp->next != NULL; temp = temp->next)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
  ```

If `temp` is `NULL` then it will attempt to access `NULL` pointer which is UB.

To delete a node in doubly linked list, you need to take care of it's previous and next pointer. The next of previous should be reset to its next node and previous of next should be reset to its previous node. If its previous is `NULL` that means its first node of the list and, in this case, reset the `head` of list to pointing to its next node.

Implementation:

```
void delete (int t) {
    struct node *temp;
    for (temp = head; temp != NULL && temp->data != t; temp = temp->next);

    if (temp == NULL) {
        printf("Target Element is Not Found\n");
        return;
    }

    if (temp->prev != NULL) {
        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
        temp->prev = NULL;
    }
    else {
        head = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp->next != NULL) {
        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

    free (temp);
}
```

Need to fix the display as well. It should be like this:

```
void display (void) {
    struct node *temp;
    printf("List->");
    for (temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
    printf ("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the element pointed to by `cur`, you need to redirect the pointer `next` of the previous and the pointer `pred` of the following, provided these elements exist. Get these elements with

```
node* pred= cur->pred, * next= cur->next;
```

Now shunt

```
(pred ? pred->next : head)= next;
(next ? next->pred : tail)= pred;
```

and release the current element:

```
delete cur;
```